# Multiple uploads to different directories using FuelPHP

Tags: php, upload, fuelphp

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with multiple uploads in FuelPHP.
Basically this is an easy task, regarding the documentation.

My problem is:
I've got two files per POST, one pdf and one jpg.

Now I want the jpg to be stored in another directory than the pdf.

Is there any possibility to do so which I might habe missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being stupid :D
I really did miss the important note in the docs.
So this is how I solved my problem:

```
Upload::process();
if(Upload::is_valid())
{
    $arr = Upload::get_files();
    //var_dump($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) 
    {
        if($arr[$i]['extension'] == 'pdf')
        {
            Upload::save($i, $catDir);
            $oldModel->catalogueFile = $arr[$i]['name'];
        }
        else if($arr[$i]['extension'] == 'jpg')
        {
            Upload::save($i, $thumbDir);
            $oldModel->catalogueImage = $arr[$i]['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy.