# Uploading multiples files to alternative directory with alternative name in FuelPHP

Tags: upload, fuelphp

I have a form having multiple upload fields. Let's assume a thumbnail image and the large image. Now using the FuelPHP how can i save this two files to two different locations renaming them to name desired.

For example: 
I want to save the thumbnail to media/images/thumbnail/db_record_id/thumbnail.extension and the large image to media/images/large/db_record_id/thumbnail.extension

using the answer to this question [Multiple uploads to different directories using FuelPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584265/multiple-uploads-to-different-directories-using-fuelphp?rq=1), I can upload to the desired directories but how to give the desired name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control, register a 'before' callback.

If will be called before saving the file, with the File object of that file. It's passed by reference, so you can alter whatever you want.